# Derby, SQL: Why do those statements return different resultsets?

Tags: sql, derby

Joined database:

```
IDDATALINE TIMESTAMP               IDDATALINE DATATYPE DATA
 ---------- ----------------------- ---------- -------- ---------
          8 2014-09-09 22:05:16.376          8        4    139789
          7 2014-09-09 22:04:07.706          7        7 457220807
          6 2014-09-05 18:08:52.231          6        4    277559
          5 2014-09-05 18:07:39.707          5        7 629011561
          4 2014-08-30 14:29:13.478          4        4    205035
          3 2014-08-30 14:26:59.562          3        7  97505332
          2 2014-08-29 11:21:54.23           2        4     71119
```

Statement 1:

```
SELECT datalines_e_3.timestamp 
FROM datalines_e_3, 
     datalong_3 
WHERE datalines_e_3.iddataline = datalong_3.iddataline 
 AND (datalong_3.data =4 OR datalong_3.datatype =5 OR datalong_3.datatype =6 OR datalong_3.datatype =7 OR datalong_3.datatype =8 OR datalong_3.datatype =9) 
 AND datalines_e_3.timestamp > '2014-09-05 18:07:39.707'
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT datalines_e_3.timestamp 
FROM datalines_e_3, 
     datalong_3 
WHERE (    datalines_e_3.iddataline = datalong_3.iddataline 
       AND datalines_e_3.timestamp > '2014-09-05 18:07:39.707'  
       AND (datalong_3.data >=4 AND datalong_3.datatype <=9)
      )
```

Resultset of Statement1 :

```
 TIMESTAMP
 -----------------------
 2014-09-09 22:04:07.706
```

Result of Statement2:

```
 TIMESTAMP
 -----------------------
 2014-09-05 18:08:52.231
 2014-09-09 22:05:16.376
 2014-09-09 22:04:07.706
```

The result that is correct for my application comes from statement2 but I don't see why Statement1 returns a different resultset.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two different conditions:

```
datalong_3.data = 4
```

is something different than

```
datalong_3.data >=4
```

I *think* what you really want is to use the column `datatype` there, not `data` so the list of `OR` conditions in the first statement should be:

```
datalong_3.datatype in (4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

(I used the `IN` clause to make this shorter)

or in the second statement you probably want:

```
datalong_3.datatype >= 4 and datalong_3.datatype <= 9
```

which can be rewritten as

```
datalong_3.datatype between 4 and 9
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me different methods for writing conditions!

Comment: @Markus: you should also start using the `JOIN` operator instead of implicit joins in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 lines are different:

```
datalong_3.data =4 OR 
datalong_3.datatype =5 OR 
datalong_3.datatype =6 OR 
datalong_3.datatype =7 OR 
datalong_3.datatype =8 OR
datalong_3.datatype =9
```

vs

```
datalong_3.data >=4 AND 
datalong_3.datatype <=9
```

Probably you should use only `data` or only `datatype`, but not both at the same time.